# Proving $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ without invoking any Taylor series knowledge base.

Tags: calculus, functions

While studying basic Taylor expansions, I came across this expansion of $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$We already know this function is positive for all $x$. But let us assume we don't know about the Taylor expansion , and try to prove this in the expanded form only, how to will we prove it ?

It's already clearly  visible for $ x > 0$ as well as for $ -1<x<0 $ . But how to prove it for $x<-1$ ? I have tried much but not able to build up a strong convincing proof.

Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks!

P.S : prove it 'WITHOUT' using $e^{x}$ function.

Comment: Having $\infty$ at the end doesn't make sense.

Comment: Using the Cauchy product it is not hard to show that the function $f$ defined by that series satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. It follows that $f(x)^{-1}=f(-x)$, so $f(x)>0$ also for $x<0$

Comment: How are you defining $e^x$ on the left-hand side (in particular, how are you specifying the number $e$)? The steps of the proof will depend where it comes from - in the end it all turns out to be the same, but you have to begin somewhere. (prove something about $e^x$ "without using the $e^x$ function" doesn't make a whole lot of sense)

Comment: Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and then $f$ satisfies the DE $$ f'=f, f(0)=1. $$ This equation has a unique solution $f(x)=e^x$. Clearly $f(x)>0$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 5):

I'll use the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), so the $0^0=1$ we use for an $x^0$ term in Taylor series gives $0^n=\delta_{n0}$ for integers $n\ge0$. Let $[x^n]f(x)$ denote the $x^n$ coefficient in $f(x)$. As @leoli hints,$$[x^n]\sum_{k,\,l\ge0}\frac{x^k(-x)^l}{k!l!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k=\frac{0^n}{n!}=\delta_{n0},$$so $\sum_{k,\,l\ge0}\frac{x^k(-x)^l}{k!l!}=\sum_n\delta_{n0}x^n=1$ and, for $x<0$,$$\sum_l\frac{(-x)^l}{l!}>0\implies\sum_k\frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{\sum_l\frac{(-x)^l}{l!}}>0.$$

Comment: Is there any other basic method , I don't know  about Cauchy product.

Comment: If $x\geq 0$, it's trivial. If $x<0$, you can compute a few terms and then use the error bound for an alternating series.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Are you able to flesh that out for large, negative $x$? Of course the relevant series does not have all decreasing terms, so you have to establish that some (possibly long) initial segment of alternating terms sums to a positive value. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on some of the hints in the comments, let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

\begin{align*}
e^{x+y} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x+y)^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^ky^{n-k}}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
&= 1 + \left(x+y\right) + \left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+xy + \frac{y^2}{2!}\right) + \left(\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^2y}{2!} + \frac{xy^2}{2!} + \frac{y^3}{3!}\right) + \ldots \\
&= \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots\right) + y\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}  + \ldots\right) + \frac{y^2}{2!}\left(1+x + \ldots\right) + \ldots \\
&= \left(1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!} + \frac{y^3}{3!} + \ldots\right)\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots\right) \\
&= e^{x}e^{y}
\end{align*}

This factoring trick is what people in the comments are calling the [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). I thought that seeing the algebra done by hand (sort of) might convince you it's not a crazy sophisticated trick. It follows easily from this identity that $e^{-x} = 1/e^{x} > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that uses only that $f'=f$, a fact that is easy to prove from the Taylor expansion of $f$.

Letting
$$
  f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!},
  $$
suppose by contradiction that there exists $x\in \mathbb R$, such that $f(x)<0$, and let
$$
  a= \sup\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x)<0\}.
  $$
Since $f$ is positive on $\mathbb R_+$, it is clear that $a$ is well defined.  Moreover, since $f$
is continuous, we have that $f(a)=0$.

Observing that $f$ is nonzero on the interval $(a,\infty )$, we see that
$$
  g(x) = \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)},
  $$
is well defined on that interval.  Moreover,  using that $f'=f$,  one has for every $x$ in $(a,\infty )$ that
$$
  g'(x) = \frac{f'(x+1)f(x) - f(x+1)f'(x)}{f(x)^2} =
  \frac{f(x+1)f(x) - f(x+1)f(x)}{f(x)^2} = 0,
  $$
so $g\equiv c$, for some constant $c$.
For every $x$ in $(a,\infty )$, one then has that
$f(x+1) = c f(x)$, whence
$$
  f(a+1) = \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x+1) = \lim_{x\to a^+}cf(x) = cf(a) =0,
  $$
contradicting the choice of $a$.